# Formatting number by 0.## in report server

Tags: reporting-services, format, report, ssrs-2008, number-formatting

I'm encountering an issue that bothers me a lot for days.
I've been searching online via 0.##, #.##, number formatting, etc., but with no conclusion

I'm setting up a report in report server and there's a column called 'account available',
which might has a number like 123; ;123.4; 123.45; 123.4567; 0

**My way to create a formatting rule is 0.##; 0.##; 0**

**`123-->123.`   I DON'T WANT this formatting, I would like it to be 123**

Below are all good, i'm very satisfied with these formatting.

```
123.4 --> 123.4
123.45 --> 123.45
123.45670 --> 123.46
0 --> 0
```

is there any kind person who would like to guide me to modify this issue? thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: your formatting looks fine to me and 123 returns 123. How and where are you applying the code?

Comment: I should have said 123 returns `123`     - with out the confusing '.'

Comment: hi Alan, thank you for your attempt. I'm encountering this issue while saving the result of the report i made on reporting service into a excel.

Comment: That wasn't clear in your question. I've added an answer which explains how to work around the bug in Excel

Answer (score 1):

This issue is a bug in Excel.

The number renders fine in SSRS but if you apply the same format string to a cell in Excel `123` is returned as `123.` as you found out.

To get around this bug in Excel you have to use an expression to set the format based on if the number is an integer or not. When exported to excel this displays as expected.

You can use an expression such as this in the `format` property.

```
=IIF(Fields!myNumberField.Value = CINT(Fields!myNumberField.Value)
    , "0"
    , "0.##; 0.##; 0"
    )
```

In SSRS it looks like this...

[image]

When Exported to Excel it looks like this

[image]

In both images, the left column is the unformatted data and the right column has the format expression applied.

**Finally**:
This bug is mentioned in several places but I'm not sure if it has been reported - it may be worth checking and reporting it yourself.

[Excel number format to only show decimals when necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007653/excel-number-format-to-only-show-decimals-when-necessary)

https://superuser.com/questions/1645944/number-format-excel-bug