# limit number of character in excel after operation

Tags: excel, vba, character, decimal, limit

In my vba code the goal is to limit the number of characters after the decimal point should be 2 places so for example 26.45, 2.45, 700.34. Right now its a endless amount of character with a run on decimal points. My vba operation works but this is what I want to limit the decimals places is below.

```
Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = 100 - ((operationOne / StartingTotal) * 100) & StrName
```

Comment: `Cell.NumberFormat = "0.00"`

Comment: @BigBen say i have a number with no decimals what you showed me here adds to 0s to it. How can i use what you have but if it does not have a decimal add nothining

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/205759/format-a-number-with-optional-decimal-places-in-excel

Comment: `Cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = Round(100 - ((operationOne / StartingTotal) * 100), 2) & StrName`

Comment: `Cell.NumberFormat = "0.##"` ?

Comment: @CLR that works but its a decimal to a number like 34 now it becomes 34. how can it just stay 34

Comment: This question is very similar and provides a few answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007653